# I add some category attribute, But cant find in admin html

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, category, category-attribute

I have add some custom category attribute. When i go for admin, i cant find any custom attribute in manage category. I went throw the code and found in

```
magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php
```

that, when I print the `$categoryAttributes` I got the value, first value is "Custom attribute" and the value i got

```
[963] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute Object
                                (
                                    [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_entity_attribute
                                    [_eventObject:protected] => attribute
                                    [_cacheTag:protected] => EAV_ATTRIBUTE
                                    [_name:protected] => 
                                    [_entity:protected] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [_backend:protected] => 
                                    [_frontend:protected] => 
                                    [_source:protected] => 
                                    [_attributeIdCache:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_dataTable:protected] => catalog_category_entity_text
                                    [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/attribute
                                    [_resource:protected] => 
                                    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/attribute_collection
                                    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                                    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [attribute_id] => 963
                                            [entity_type_id] => 9
                                            [attribute_code] => custom_attribute
                                            [attribute_model] => catalog/resource_eav_attribute
                                            [backend_model] => 
                                            [backend_type] => text
                                            [backend_table] => 
                                            [frontend_model] => 
                                            [frontend_input] => textarea
                                            [frontend_label] => Custom attribute
                                            [frontend_class] => 
                                            [source_model] => 
                                            [is_required] => 0
                                            [is_user_defined] => 0
                                            [default_value] => 
                                            [is_unique] => 0
                                            [note] => 
                                            [frontend_input_renderer] => 
                                            [is_global] => 1
                                            [is_visible] => 1
                                            [is_searchable] => 0
                                            [is_filterable] => 0
                                            [is_comparable] => 0
                                            [is_visible_on_front] => 1
                                            [is_html_allowed_on_front] => 0
                                            [is_used_for_price_rules] => 0
                                            [is_filterable_in_search] => 0
                                            [used_in_product_listing] => 0
                                            [used_for_sort_by] => 0
                                            [is_configurable] => 1
                                            [apply_to] => 
                                            [is_visible_in_advanced_search] => 0
                                            [position] => 0
                                            [is_wysiwyg_enabled] => 0
                                            [is_used_for_promo_rules] => 0
                                            [attribute_set_info] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [12] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [group_id] => 7
                                                            [group_sort] => 10
                                                            [sort] => 25
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                                    [_origData:protected] => 
                                    [_idFieldName:protected] => attribute_id
                                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )
```

Second attribute is "Best" and the value i got

```
[962] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute Object
                                (
                                    [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_entity_attribute
                                    [_eventObject:protected] => attribute
                                    [_cacheTag:protected] => EAV_ATTRIBUTE
                                    [_name:protected] => 
                                    [_entity:protected] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category Object
 *RECURSION*
                                    [_backend:protected] => 
                                    [_frontend:protected] => 
                                    [_source:protected] => 
                                    [_attributeIdCache:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_dataTable:protected] => catalog_category_entity_varchar
                                    [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/attribute
                                    [_resource:protected] => 
                                    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/attribute_collection
                                    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                                    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [attribute_id] => 962
                                            [entity_type_id] => 9
                                            [attribute_code] => best
                                            [attribute_model] => catalog/resource_eav_attribute
                                            [backend_model] => 
                                            [backend_type] => varchar
                                            [backend_table] => 
                                            [frontend_model] => 
                                            [frontend_input] => text
                                            [frontend_label] => BEST
                                            [frontend_class] => 
                                            [source_model] => 
                                            [is_required] => 0
                                            [is_user_defined] => 0
                                            [default_value] => 
                                            [is_unique] => 0
                                            [note] => 
                                            [frontend_input_renderer] => 
                                            [is_global] => 1
                                            [is_visible] => 1
                                            [is_searchable] => 0
                                            [is_filterable] => 0
                                            [is_comparable] => 0
                                            [is_visible_on_front] => 1
                                            [is_html_allowed_on_front] => 0
                                            [is_used_for_price_rules] => 0
                                            [is_filterable_in_search] => 0
                                            [used_in_product_listing] => 0
                                            [used_for_sort_by] => 0
                                            [is_configurable] => 1
                                            [apply_to] => 
                                            [is_visible_in_advanced_search] => 0
                                            [position] => 0
                                            [is_wysiwyg_enabled] => 0
                                            [is_used_for_promo_rules] => 0
                                            [attribute_set_info] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                                    [_origData:protected] => 
                                    [_idFieldName:protected] => attribute_id
                                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )
```

Now my problem is whether i got the value in this file. One custom attribute is displayed in the admin "Custom Attribute", but the other "Best" attribute is not displayed in the admin.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to add it?

Comment: I use the http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-attributes-4340.html extension for save custom category attribute.

Comment: Maybe you should contact the extension developer.

Comment: When you were searching for your custom attribute did you search for 'Best' or 'BEST' as the frontend label is all in caps.

Comment: Yes i did everything. Now i got some extra clue. Like in the "customerController" and "AddressController", i got this code     if($this->_block == 'customer' || $this->_block == 'address')
    {
     $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($id);
     Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
     ->getAttribute($this->_type, $attribute->getAttributeCode())
     ->setData('used_in_forms', $data['customer_form'])
     ->save();
    }" If you see there is no codition for category. So can you help me to know the condition for category.

Comment: Had similiar problem see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117135/custom-category-attribute/117161#117161 Let me know if that fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the second attribute is not assigned to a set. When building all the tabs in the admin section for categories the system will load each set as a tab. So if your attribute is not assigned to a set it will not show via the admin section on a category as there is no tab to attach the attribute to.

If you add these attributes to a set, either a new one or an existing one, then they will show up. This can be done via the admin section under `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribute Sets` then select the set you want the attributes to be under using the drag and drop. Or you can add attributes to sets via set-up scripts with the function `addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId, $setId, $groupId, $attributeId, $sortOrder=null)`

**First Attribute**

```
[attribute_set_info] => Array
(
    [12] => Array
    (
        [group_id] => 7
        [group_sort] => 10
        [sort] => 25
    )
)
```

**Second attribute**

```
[attribute_set_info] => Array
(
)
```